# Is there a priority_queue adaptor for boost pointer containers?

Tags: boost, priority-queue, pointer-container

Is there a priority_queue adaptor that works with boost pointer containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priority queue is not really a new container. You should be able to "create" it based on a `ptr_vector` using a typedef:

```
typedef priority_queue<myclass, ptr_vector<myclass> > ptr_priority_queue;
```